# Show message box in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, visual-studio-2012

I currently have the following screen below:

[image]

I keep getting the error "End of statement expected" as shown below:

[image]

How should I end the statements to get this to work?

Comment: This is not vba.  vb.net<> vba

Comment: Post code, not images of code.

Comment: Remove # and put MessageBox commands on the next line

Comment: 1) Code here in post where we can see it. 2) Errors here *in text* where it can be read. 3) Learn what language you're using, and only use the relevant tag. VB <> VB.NET <> VBA - they're entirely different even though they all start with VB, just like *car* and *carrot* are not the same thing even though they both start with *ca*.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter The code isn't inside any kind of method.

Comment: You probably want to start with some introductory tutorials on VB .NET.  Just randomly typing stuff that looks like code into the IDE isn't a particularly effective approach.

Comment: @LarsTech good point. Haven't even noticed after seeing the rest

Answer (score 1):

This will run your code when either Radio Button is selected. I'd consider spending time looking at other questions or other sources for syntax help.

```
Public Class Greetings
Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged, RadioButton2.CheckedChanged

    If RadioButton1.Checked Then
        MessageBox.Show("Hello")
    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked Then
        MessageBox.Show("Goodbye")
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```